# Apply HTML tag to text instead of strip them when reading from SQL Server

Tags: html, database, strip

I have a problem when trying to read text HTML fields from database. basically, I have a short HTML snippet as below, it has been saved to the database as one row:

```html
<UL>
    <LI>Metal stamp: 14k </LI>
    <LI>Metal: yellow-gold</LI>
    <LI>Material Type: amethyst, citrine, gold, pearl, peridot</LI>
    <LI>Gem Type: citrine, peridot, amethyst</LI>
    <LI>Length: 7.5 inches</LI>
    <LI>Clasp Type: filigree-box</LI>
    <LI>Total metal weight: 0.6 Grams</LI>
</UL>
<STRONG>Pearl Information</STRONG><BR>
<UL>
    <LI>Pearl type: freshwater-cultured</LI>
</UL>
<STRONG>Packaging Information</STRONG><BR>
<UL>
    <LI>Package: Regal Blue Sueded-Cloth Pouch</LI>
</UL>
```

I'm trying to find a way to strip all HTML tags from main text, then read it to a model in MVC. Finally, I need to apply these tags to this main text again.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the guide to asking a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Specifically please note the link re providing a complete, minimal, verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MatthewEvans thanks for your editing.

Comment: You need to add more information so we can answer the question. What language are you using? Can you post the code which you have tried?